# Event handler in SignalR hub

Tags: c#, signalr, autofac

I'm facing the following problem. I have a SignalR hub like this:

```
public class NewsLetterHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IServicesContainer _servicesContainer;
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _hubLifetimeScope;

    public NewsLetterHub(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope, IServicesContainer servicesContainer)
    {
        _servicesContainer = servicesContainer;
        _hubLifetimeScope = lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope();

        _servicesContainer.NewsLetterService.ImportProgress += _sentNewsLetter_Progress;
    }
```

I register this hub in Autofac this way:

```
builder.RegisterHubs(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Debugging the code I see that hub constructor is called once per request but the `ImportProgress` event contains the previous registered handler. This brings `_sentNewsLetter_Progress` method to be executed multiple times.

I tryied to register the hub this way:

```
builder.RegisterHubs(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Doing this it seems to work but I don't know if this is the right solution (it becomes singleton).

I also tryied to unregister the event:

```
_servicesContainer.NewsLetterService.ImportProgress -= _sentNewsLetter_Progress;
_servicesContainer.NewsLetterService.ImportProgress += _sentNewsLetter_Progress;
```

But it seems to do nothing.

How to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change where you're de-registering the event handler to do it in a destructor or Dispose() method.  If you try to do in the constructor it will try to de-register the _sentNewsLetter_Progress handler from the instance being constructed.  Since that instance isn't registered yet it will do nothing.  However, if you de-register in the destructor/Dispose then it will work.

Comment: Adding on to this, I'm not sure if this is the design you're looking for. Are you trying to post a message to all connected clients when the Progress event is fired? If so, you'll need to register an event handler in a singleton somewhere (could be the static constructor of the hub) and invoke something like `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NewsLetterHub>().Clients.All.progress()`. See [the SignalR documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub) for an example.